# WPF TreeView selection over entire HierarchyItem

Tags: wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView bound to an MVVM observable collection.
My item template is composed by an image and a textblock like the following code show:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image 
                    Margin="-20,0,5,0"
                    Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource TreeViewIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
                    Style="{DynamicResource SmallIcon}"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding Label}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem.Header>
    </TreeViewItem>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The problem happens when you Click over an item. If the Mouse cursor is over the StackPanel, the selection will not happen.
I have included also a screenshot to make this more clear.
[image]

Of course this happens because the StackPanel is now **over** the selection area.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.
When you customize the TreeView using an **hierarchical data template** then you should not replicate the TreeViewItem.Header template because at runtime WPF will create one for you.
So, in order to have a custom TreeViewItem this code is enough:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TreeViewItemTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image 
            Margin="0,0,5,0"
            Source="{Binding Icon, Converter={StaticResource TreeViewIconConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" 
            Style="{DynamicResource SmallIcon}"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Label}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```